# How can i catch the 8th element of the menu to open in new tab

Tags: jquery

I have a menu and i want to catch it's 8th element. I want to open this URL in a new tab. I tried this but it didn't work. Ι got no errors in the console and the URL still opens in the same window.

```
<script>
jQuery('ul#main-menu li:nth-child(8) a').click(function() {
   window.open("https://google.com", '_blank');
});         
</script>
```

Comment: For me, it seems to be working... What not worked for you? Some error in console, what happened?

Comment: No errors in the console, it just opens in the same tab

Comment: That's an important information to add to your question, people doesn't have a crystal ball to know what problem are you facing. Please, [edit] the question to add relevant informations, explaining what is happening and what should happen

Comment: For me, its working fine. Please can you share your html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the selector `ul#main-menu li:nth-child(8) a` it actually looks correct to me even though I'm not sure what you html looks like

You need to stop the default action of a link of `a` tag click,which would naturally to go to the specified `href`

this is what you need to do

```
<script>
    jQuery('ul#main-menu li:nth-child(8) a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("https://google.com", '_blank');
    });         
</script>
```

see more info about [preventDefault()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)